# Xamarin Forms FontSize by Platform

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, font-size, staticresource

There is a known issue with UWP Xamarin Apps in that the size that fonts render in for Windows Mobile (not sure about Desktop Windows 10) are MUCH larger than they render on the other two platforms iOS and Android.  The fix I have found a for this is to put a numeric font size with a decimal point in it (for example 24.1 for Large font size) in UWP apps.  This works great.  What I would like not is to define a static resource in my App.xaml that will work for all platforms.  What I tried, that obviously does not work, is the following:

```
        <OnPlatform x:Key="CustLarge" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS|Android">Large</On>
            <On Platform="UWP">24.1</On>
        </OnPlatform>
```

The theory is that in my XAML I would simply code all my large font sizes as "CustLarge" like this:

```
FontSize = "{StaticResource CustLarge}" />
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this without doing on OnPlatform for every FontSize in my app?  Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:  Below are screen shots of what I am talking about.  The iOS emulator was for the iPhone 6 4.7" wide.  The Windows 10 emulator was a the 10.0.15254.9 5" phone.

[image: iOS emulator]

[image: Windows Mobile Emulator]

You can see the Map All text is way bigger than it should be.  (I am doing a relative comparison to the text in the segment control to the right of the stand alone buttons.) In both cases the fontsize is set to MICRO.

So back to my question - does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: First off, you should use `,` (comma) separator instead of `|`, when defining more than one platform for a resource (as per the [`On` code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9b49e3f1c1f82a05bb1f282cd5b251228a357ae7/Xamarin.Forms.Core/OnPlatform.cs#L87) and the [`ListStringTypeConverter`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/9618f158bb4e3c6de6e696fc59d3f659796f5304/Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks/CompiledConverters/ListStringTypeConverter.cs#L25))

Comment: I have tested with Xamarin .NetStandard and it woks well. Do you use Xamarin PCL?

Comment: Yes this is a PCL using Xamarin Forms and this is a documented issue with UWP app regarding the font size.

Comment: Regarding the use of comma, I have use the | (bar separator) per Xamarin XAML document.  If their documentation regarding onplatform in XAML has changed and you could please provide me a link to the updated documentation, I would appreciate it,

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr I have tested with Xamarin.Forms v2.4.0.91020. it works well please try to update to the same version (contain the nuget package that installed in uwp platform).

Comment: @NicoZhu - Are you testing on a windows 10 phone emulator?  That is what I am speaking of.  Also Xamarin From 2.4.0.... is very old.  I am running 3.1.0.697729  Regardless, if someone can actually answer the question of how you can pass in a named value for some platforms and a numeric value for other platforms, that would be helpful.

Comment: I have tested in lumia 950,

Comment: NicoZhu - please see my screen shots above that clearly show the problem.

Comment: Have you used `NamedSize` just like this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts) ?

Comment: Using the named sizes is what generated the very different sizes as shown above.  Named sized do not seem to translate correctly for UWP apps.  That is why I am trying to specify a numeric font size for UWP apps but a named fontsize for iOS and Android.

Comment: We are having the same issue, have you reached any conclusion on this one or a workaround?

Comment: @NicoZhu - you can clearly see that the fonts are not done correctly for UWP apps by adding the following code to the constructor of any XAML page  var size = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label));  Set a breakpoint at that line of code then run it on an iPhone 6 simulator (which has a 4.7" screen size).  The value (i.e. font size) will show as 12.  Then run the same code on a Windows Mobile emulator WVGA 4".  When you do you will see the value returned is 15.667.  So on a smaller, lower resolution screen, the font is bigger.  I really hope Microsoft addresses this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround by creating a custom ResourceDictionnary, and adding FontSizes in the constructor.

```
public class SResourceDictionnary : ResourceDictionary
{
    public SResourceDictionnary()
    {
        Add("Micro", new OnPlatform<double>
        {
            Default = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)),
            Platforms = { new On
                {
                    Value = 12d,
                    Platform = new List<string>{"UWP"}
                }
            }
        });
        Add("Small", new OnPlatform<double>
        {
            Default = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
            Platforms = { new On
                {
                    Value = 14d,
                    Platform = new List<string>{"UWP"}
                }
            }
        });
        Add("Medium", new OnPlatform<double>
        {
            Default = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            Platforms = { new On
                {
                    Value = 18d,
                    Platform = new List<string>{"UWP"}
                }
            }
        });
        Add("Large", new OnPlatform<double>
        {
            Default = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            Platforms = { new On
                {
                    Value = 20d,
                    Platform = new List<string>{"UWP"}
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Then I merged the dictionary in my App.xaml like this

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <helpers:SResourceDictionnary></helpers:SResourceDictionnary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource Small}" ></Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It allowed me to use FontSize as StaticResource.
The only disadvantage is that you lose intellisense in Xaml

Comment: Thanks Elias - this sounds great.  I will try it out.

Comment: Elias, with this work for any control type?  I see that you are referencing the named size as it applies to Label controls so I wanted to double check.

Comment: I'm using Label for Button and Entry, it is working fine. But you can create for each control a resource size.

Comment: So this does appear to work.  In your App.xaml be sure to add and assembly reference to your project - something like this xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:GBarScene;assembly=GBarScene"  In this case, ctrl would replace helpers in Elias' sample code